# Jenkins: how to backup projects without workspace

Tags: jenkins, backup

I want to take a backup of all my projects, which is in the \jobs folder, but most of it are the workspaces which is also very big.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [thinBackup plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/thinBackup).

This plugin backup all the xml files of your Jenkins server.

They are a lot of options if you want to backup more stuff:

[image]